# Getting return values from codedom results's method

Tags: c#, reflection, codedom

i have compiled .cs file using `codedom` and extract its method through `invokemember`. but how can i get a value from that method? for example: i want to get webcontrol that has been created in the method

here's my code

```
    string[] filepath = new string[1];
        filepath[0] = @"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\xxx\xx\invokerteks.cs";

        CodeDomProvider cpd = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.dll");
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
        CompilerResults cr = cpd.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, filepath);

        if (true == cr.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            foreach (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError ce in cr.Errors)
            {
                sb.Append(ce.ToString());
                sb.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
        }

        Assembly invokerAssm = cr.CompiledAssembly;
        Type invokerType = invokerAssm.GetType("dynamic.hello");
        object invokerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(invokerType);

        invokerType.InvokeMember("helloworld", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, invokerInstance, null);
```

and here's my `invokerteks.cs`

```
    namespace dinamis
    {
public class halo
{
    private void halodunia()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!!");

    }
}
```

}

can you provide me a links tutorial for this issue?

Comment: Just return whatever you want from the method and it will be returned out of `InvokeMember()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvokeMember` will return whatever is returned by the method. Since your helloworld method has `void` as it's return, nothing will be returned. In order to get something out, define your return type and invoke as usual:

```
public class Hello
{
    private int helloworld()
    { 
        return new Random().NextInt();
    }
}
```

Which can be called like:

```
var type = typeof(Hello);
int value = (int)type.InvokeMember("helloworld", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, invokerInstance, null);
```

`InvokeMember` always returns and instance of `object` so you have to cast to your desired type. Be careful for invalid casts here.